# iPhone - create custom button like Foursquare

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button

Do you know how to create Twitter and Facebook buttons like the one in Foursquare application?
(without NIB files!)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head a way to do this is to do something like this.

- Create a graphic that looks like the button
- Subclass UIControl so you can use the built in click actions
- In the UIControl subclass instantiate a UIImageView with the graphic and add it to the UIControl.

You should be able to then set the frame of the UIControl subclass and add your control to your screen.

Or you can use a UIButton and leave as custom and add the image to it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom `UIButtons` with custom style. Then add pictures of FB and Twitter to them with the required state